# XSLT 1.0: sorting nodes changes structure

Tags: xslt, sorting

I have the following simplified XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<INVOIC02>
<IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
        <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
    </EDI_DC40>
    <E1EDP01 SEGMENT="1">
        <MENGE>1.000</MENGE>
        <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
            <QUALF>002</QUALF>
            <IDTNR>000000000000718221</IDTNR>
            <KTEXT>Orange</KTEXT>
        </E1EDP19>
        <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
            <QUALF>Z03</QUALF>
            <IDTNR>7610400013079</IDTNR>
        </E1EDP19>
    </E1EDP01>
    <E1EDP01 SEGMENT="1">
        <MENGE>1.000</MENGE>
        <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
            <QUALF>002</QUALF>
            <IDTNR>000000000000718160</IDTNR>
            <KTEXT>Pistache</KTEXT>
        </E1EDP19>     
        <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
            <QUALF>003</QUALF>
            <IDTNR>7610400181600</IDTNR>
        </E1EDP19>
    </E1EDP01>
    <E1EDP01 SEGMENT="1">
        <MENGE>1.000</MENGE>
        <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
            <QUALF>002</QUALF>
            <IDTNR>000000000000718228</IDTNR>
            <KTEXT>Strawberry</KTEXT>
        </E1EDP19>
        <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
            <QUALF>003</QUALF>
            <IDTNR>7610400182287</IDTNR>
        </E1EDP19>
    </E1EDP01>
    <E1EDP01 SEGMENT="1">
        <MENGE>1.000</MENGE>
        <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
            <QUALF>002</QUALF>
            <IDTNR>000000000000718221</IDTNR>
            <KTEXT>Orange</KTEXT>
        </E1EDP19>
        <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
            <QUALF>003</QUALF>
            <IDTNR>7610400182218</IDTNR>
        </E1EDP19>
    </E1EDP01>
    <E1EDP01 SEGMENT="1">
        <MENGE>1.000</MENGE>
        <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
            <QUALF>002</QUALF>
            <IDTNR>000000000000718160</IDTNR>
            <KTEXT>Pistache</KTEXT>
        </E1EDP19>
        <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
            <QUALF>003</QUALF>
            <IDTNR>7610400181600</IDTNR>
        </E1EDP19>
    </E1EDP01>
    <E1EDP01 SEGMENT="1">
        <MENGE>1.000</MENGE>
        <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
            <QUALF>002</QUALF>
            <IDTNR>000000000000718228</IDTNR>
            <KTEXT>Strawberry</KTEXT>
        </E1EDP19>
        <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
            <QUALF>003</QUALF>
            <IDTNR>7610400182287</IDTNR>
        </E1EDP19>
    </E1EDP01>
    <E1EDS01 SEGMENT="1">
        <SUMID>001</SUMID>
        <SUMME>6</SUMME>
    </E1EDS01>
</IDOC>
</INVOIC02>
```

I need to sort the `<E1EDP01 SEGMENT="1">` segments by their `<IDTNR>` number with QUALF='002'

So I came up with this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="IDOC">
    <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:sort select="E1EDP19[QUALF='002']/IDTNR"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>     
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But in my Output the `<E1EDP01>` Segments are sorted but are put at the end of my structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<INVOIC02>
<EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
    <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
</EDI_DC40>
<E1EDS01 SEGMENT="1">
    <SUMID>001</SUMID>
    <SUMME>6</SUMME>
</E1EDS01>
<E1EDP01 SEGMENT="1">
    <MENGE>1.000</MENGE>
    <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
        <QUALF>002</QUALF>
        <IDTNR>000000000000718160</IDTNR>
        <KTEXT>Pistache</KTEXT>
    </E1EDP19>
    <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
        <QUALF>003</QUALF>
        <IDTNR>7610400181600</IDTNR>
    </E1EDP19>
</E1EDP01>
<E1EDP01 SEGMENT="1">
    <MENGE>1.000</MENGE>
    <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
        <QUALF>002</QUALF>
        <IDTNR>000000000000718160</IDTNR>
        <KTEXT>Pistache</KTEXT>
    </E1EDP19>
    <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
        <QUALF>003</QUALF>
        <IDTNR>7610400181600</IDTNR>
    </E1EDP19>
</E1EDP01>
<E1EDP01 SEGMENT="1">
    <MENGE>1.000</MENGE>
    <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
        <QUALF>002</QUALF>
        <IDTNR>000000000000718221</IDTNR>
        <KTEXT>Orange</KTEXT>
    </E1EDP19>
    <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
        <QUALF>Z03</QUALF>
        <IDTNR>7610400013079</IDTNR>
    </E1EDP19>
</E1EDP01>
<E1EDP01 SEGMENT="1">
    <MENGE>1.000</MENGE>
    <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
        <QUALF>002</QUALF>
        <IDTNR>000000000000718221</IDTNR>
        <KTEXT>Orange</KTEXT>
    </E1EDP19>
    <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
        <QUALF>003</QUALF>
        <IDTNR>7610400182218</IDTNR>
    </E1EDP19>
</E1EDP01>
<E1EDP01 SEGMENT="1">
    <MENGE>1.000</MENGE>
    <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
        <QUALF>002</QUALF>
        <IDTNR>000000000000718228</IDTNR>
        <KTEXT>Strawberry</KTEXT>
    </E1EDP19>
    <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
        <QUALF>003</QUALF>
        <IDTNR>7610400182287</IDTNR>
    </E1EDP19>
</E1EDP01>
<E1EDP01 SEGMENT="1">
    <MENGE>1.000</MENGE>
    <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
        <QUALF>002</QUALF>
        <IDTNR>000000000000718228</IDTNR>
        <KTEXT>Strawberry</KTEXT>
    </E1EDP19>
    <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
        <QUALF>003</QUALF>
        <IDTNR>7610400182287</IDTNR>
    </E1EDP19>
</E1EDP01>
</INVOIC02>
```

The `<E1EDS01>` segment comes before the sorted segments but should be at the end. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you sort everything and non-E1EDP01 elements are going to have empty sort keys.
instead, you could force their position, like:

```
<xsl:template match="IDOC">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="EDI_DC40"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="E1EDP01">
        <xsl:sort select="E1EDP19[QUALF='002']/IDTNR"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>     
    <xsl:apply-templates select="E1EDS01"/>
</xsl:template>
```